# How to hide AJAX HTML Editor Bottom Toolbar

Tags: asp.net, ajax

How do we hide Ajax Control Tool Kits Bottom Tool bar where it has Design mode HTML mode and preview Buttons.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;

using System.Web;
using AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor;

namespace MyCustomControls
{
public class MyCustomEditor: Editor
{
    protected override void FillBottomToolbar()
    {   
        //Do not add any buttons in the bottom toolbar
        //BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.DesignMode());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

There's probably other ways to do it via code, but I'm lazy and just added the following CSS:

```
.ajax__htmleditor_editor_bottomtoolbar {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example if you want to hide the Pharagraph toolbar item then replace this code

```
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Paragraph, 
  {"activeModesIds":"0","activeSrc":this.get_imagesPath()
  +"ed_format_paragraph_a.gif","downSrc":this.get_imagesPath()
  +"ed_format_paragraph_a.gif","normalSrc":this.get_imagesPath()+"ed_format_paragraph_n.gif"}, 
  null, null, $get(id+"_ctl01_ctl35"));
```

in AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ClientSideEditor.js
with this

```
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Paragraph, null, null, null, $get(id+"_ctl01_ctl35"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Toolbar test = (AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Toolbar)Editor1.Controls[0].Controls[2].Controls[0].Controls[0];

test.Buttons.ToList().ForEach(delegate(AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.CommonButton x)
{
  x.Enabled = false;
});
```